# How do I get a notification bubble when I get new mail in Evolution?

Tags: 11.04, evolution

I apologize if this has been asked before. I could not find the relevant post.

I want to see a popup every time a mail comes through, right now, when I get a mail, I see a change in the color of the applet. Previously when I was using 10.04 and 9.04, I used to get a pop-up that would let me know that I had a mail.

Comment: @Jorge, not a duplicate. Not related.

Comment: Ok I've edited your title to make that a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to install Evolution Indicator which can be easily done by dropping the next in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator
```

Provide your user password and wait for the installation process to finish, this should take a minute or two.

Then remove the "Indicator applet" from your panel and add it again in order to the panel get the news of the new installed mail indicator.

Reboot your machine.

After rebooting, the "Setup Mail" icon will be in the list of the Indicator Applet icons, clic on it and it will emerge the Evolution Mail client, after which you can set up your mail services and when finished, the evolution indicator will work as we are used to.

Source: ***[How to install evolution and evolution indicator applet in Israel Remix Team](http://www.israelremixteam.com/how-to-install-evolution-and-evolution-indicator-t707.html)***

Comment: Surely logging out and back in is sufficent for an indicator instead of rebooting?

Comment: Sometimes logging out and back in hasn't been enough for me. However, feel free to try and if it doesn't do the trick for you, a reboot will. Thank you @Jorge Castro

Comment: How do you remove the indicator applet? (I am using the new interface of 11.04)

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure the evolution indicator is installed. (I see a change in color of my indicator applet) What is lacking is the a notification bubble as Jorge pointed out, i.e. a message that appears when a mail does so I see it right away. I am not that prone to notice a color change, but I see a notification bubble no matter what I am doing.